# How to Set the Line Length for VS2010 Automatic line break

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, text-editor, setting

I use a wide screen and like to code in 16:9. So sometimes there is a `string.Format`... or whatever the is larger than the old 4:3 screen format. But VS does not want to use the avaiable space and just always makes a line break at about 50% of the visible line.

Where can I adjust the automatic line break to the wider screen?

btw I am using ReSharper (5.1).

example:

[image]

Comment: [URL=http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/9/vs2010linebreaks.png/][IMG]http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/159/vs2010linebreaks.png[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop Resharper from line breaking after return keyword for long lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509768/how-to-stop-resharper-from-line-breaking-after-return-keyword-for-long-lines)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think this is ReSharper's doing. In `ReSharper | Options | Languages | C# | Formatting style | Line Breaks and Wrapping`, under `Line wrapping` there is an entry **Right margin (columns)** - adjust this upwards to match the width you want ReSharper to wrap to.

I don't believe VS on its own will reflow text.

Note that there is a VS option to *display* wrapped text (`Edit | Advanced | Word Wrap`), but as can be seen from the line numbers when this is turned on, that doesn't actually change the text.